# How can I set enabled to a button only If the user types in numbers in the input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the component which has an input and a button to submit when user types in input :

```
const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState(null);

const handle = (e) => {
        setValue(e);
};
```

```
<input pattern="*[0-9]*" type="text" value={value} onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value)} />

<button disabled={value && typeof value === 'number' ? false : true} type="submit">
                        Search
</button>
```

What I want to do is set the button to disabled when user types in a string value in the input and the button is only enabled when user types in a numeric value in the input but it doesn't work.

How can I set the button to disabled when user types in the alphabet in the input and set the button to enable only when user types in numbers in the input?

Comment: Why not use `type="number"`? Side note, `typeof value === 'number' ? false : true` is needlessly verbose. In cases like this you can always shorten this to just `typeof value === 'number'`, which will evaluate to either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the type from text to number. Even if you change it to number, your input would accept the text they type in the field. You can add [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) check in the submit button

```
<input type="number" value={value} onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value)} />

<button disabled={!isNaN(value)} type="submit">Search</button>
```

You can also handle this logic in the function rather than handling it in the jsx:

```
const handle = (val) => {
  if (!isNaN(val)) {
    setValue(val);
  }
};

<input type="number" value={value} onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value)} />

<button disabled={!value} type="submit">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the JQuery library, you could use something like this:

```js
$("#your_input").on("input", function() {
    if (isNaN($("#your_input").val())) {
        $("#your_button").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#your_button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="your_input" type="text">
<button id="your_button" type="submit">Search</button>
```

It detects if the input has been changed, and checks whether the input value is a number using the `isNaN()` function. If it's not a number, then it disables the button. Give your elements the appropriate IDs if you use this.